# Unable to successfully load dataset with pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, google-colaboratory, loading

I am loading the dataset from "http://snap.stanford.edu/data/amazon/productGraph/categoryFiles/reviews_Electronics_
5.json.gz" and faced an issue of trailing space which I corrected by enabling lines parameter. So my current code is as given below:

```
    `data = pd.read_json('Electronics_5.json', lines=True)`
```

But now I am facing the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-35ecfcbcbeb6> in <module>()
----> 1 data = pd.read_json('Electronics_5.json', lines=True)
      2 print(data.head())

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py in _parse_no_numpy(self)
   1087         if orient == "columns":
   1088             self.obj = DataFrame(
-> 1089                 loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
   1090             )
   1091         elif orient == "split":

ValueError: Unmatched ''"' when when decoding 'string'
```

I am programming on google colab.

Comment: i was able to run this just fine using the same code as you - `data = pd.read_json('/Users/khuynh/Downloads/reviews_Electronics_5.json', lines=True)`. It's possible your file is corrupted or not complete. I'd suggest redownloading the file.

Comment: Hey @khuynh thank you sparing your time , I tried it by downloading it again, the problem persisted. Is there something else I may do? looks tough tho as it looks like the download itself is messing up but I did try it instantly without opening the json . Also I am doing this program on google colab.

Comment: the link you provided was broken, but I think i was able to find it here: http://snap.stanford.edu/data/amazon/productGraph/categoryFiles/reviews_Electronics_5.json.gz , other than that, I'm not sure. I'm not able to reproduce the issue :/

Comment: Thank you so much, the original link was broken itself. When I ran the program on the dataset from the link you gave it worked.

Comment: One sec, it is exactly the same link. It worked now tho, probably messed it up somehow. I think when I moved it between folders it may have messed up, idk. Thank you for helping.

Comment: no problem, glad i could help. if you could be so kind to add an edit to your original post with the solution (explanation and updated link), that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Redownloading from this link: http://snap.stanford.edu/data/amazon/productGraph/categoryFiles/reviews_Electronics_5.json.gz solved it.

(FYI, moving the file may cause an error.)

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63691701/3) to the question [Unable to successfully load dataset with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63691701/unable-to-successfully-load-dataset-with-pandas) by the OP [Shivam Mangale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11267248/shivam-mangale) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>